# Unable to autoload constant error - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using ruby 2.7 and rails 5.2 in my application. The application uses a lot of namespaces. The issue is that sometimes i get an error like

```
Unable to autoload constant Api::V1::OrdersController
```

At other time it will be something like

```
Unable to autoload constant Api::V1::ProductController
```

This happens with different controllers, and reloading the page fixes it.

The path to the file is as follows

app/controllers/api/v1/orders_controller.rb

app/controllers/api/v1/product_controller.rb

Any idea on how to fix this?

**Edit**: The modules are written in "long-form" as follows.

```
module Api
  module V1
    class OrdersController < Api::V1::ApplicationController
```

Comment: Is there any way in which controllers where this does not happen differ from the controllers where it does? Has any customization been done to autoloading configuration? Does this happen in `-e production`?

Comment: There is an issue reported in production which i assume the reason would be this. All controllers follow the same pattern. No customisation has been done to the autoloading configuration.

Comment: Why not `ProductsController` to follow the convention?